# Including start year and end year in YEAR calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For the calculation I'm trying to perform one year = one season and the data I have is start year and end year.

So 1952 1953 needs to add up to 2 (seasons) but if I use `=YEAR(A1)-YEAR(A2)` the result is `0` - is there a simple way to include the start year and end year as a value in these calculations?

Comment: @AnnL. A1 = 1952 A2 = 1953 - apologies for the confusion - the data has lower year value first.

Comment: If A1 and A2 are year numbers, not dates, is there some reason why `(A2-A1)+1` won't work?

Comment: @AnnL. Good idea - that works perfectly. I was so obsessed with the data being years I failed to see the obvious. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have found the problem and rectified it. For the benefit of others who might have found this thread, this is why it was behaving the ways it was.

> Background - Excel (and many other applications) treat dates as 1 for every day past *Dec 31, 1899*. Today happens to be *42,079*. Time is a decimal portion of a day so *42,079.75* would be *Mar 16, 2015 06:00 PM*.

You had the years as numbers in A1:A2; not as full dates. Using the *1-per-day* formula, 1952 is *May 5, 1905* and 1953 is *May 6, 1905*. If you peel out the year of each of those with the `YEAR()` function, you are subtracting 1905 from 1905; resulting in zero.

The solution would be to either type full dates into A1:A2 and format the cells as *yyyy* so they display 1952 & 1953 but retain their full date nature e.g. `=ABS(YEAR(A1) - YEAR(A2)) + 1` , or use the years as numbers only and discard the `YEAR()` function altogether, e.g. `=ABS(A1 - A2) + 1` to get the spanned (inclusive) number of seasons.